# From SQL to SPSS

Tags: c#, .net, sql, spss

I need to export some data and then I have to export them in a SPSS file format.

I've already found out that I need a SPSS SDK. I also have found out that i need a I/O DLL for creating and reading these files.

But I cannot find them.
Can anybody please send me the direct link, as it seems that I'm too dumb to find it.

Please help!

Thanks in advance

PS: I just need to create some SPPS files and I don't have any SPSS licence.

EDIT:
it'a an webapplication on the internet, and the client wants us to generate SPSS files, so he can download it make some statistics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the SPSS I/O materials from the SPSS Community site at
www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral.  Free registration required.

These materials allow you to build an application in C, Basic or other languages that can read or write SPSS sav files.  Doc and libraries are provided for a bunch of platforms.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Comment: i've searched in die files directory, but they are linked in the wiki part :-) after reading your post here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=344508&tstart=0 i've found it...  thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your SPSS user is in your organization, they can connect to your SQL source with ODBC and then you won't need your SSIS package.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is that we don't have any spss users here... the application is on the internet, and the client wants to download spss files

Comment: can they take it in a more generic format that SSIS supports?

Comment: i dont think so... the spss files are for some researchers, they just want to have SPSS files, so they do not have to convert anything... there are more than 200 columns in the report :-(

Comment: they should be able to import in multiple formats, our spss guy has taken them in csv, and see http://www.childrens-mercy.org/stats/data/access.asp

Comment: i know that there are some csv and excel import tools, but the problem is you have to define the type of each columns - at least that whats the client said.. i've never worked with spss so i don't know if there is an easier solution...