# Read .SAV or SPSS file from c# code

Tags: c#-4.0, spss

May you please suggest me that, is it possible to `read .SAV` file from Code behind in c#? If `yes` then you may guide me about the procedure and the dll's.

Can we convert `.SAV to .CSV` from code behind C#.

Comment: [From SQL to SPSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392789/from-sql-to-spss)

Answer (score -2):

SPSS makes available free libraries that provide apis for reading and writing sav files.  They would need some slight wrapping for use with C#.  You can obtain these libraries and their documentation from the SPSS Community website at www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral in the Downloads for SPSS Statistics section.